# Photoshop - Crop the sides of an image down to the borders of an object

Tags: adobe-photoshop, crop

For example, turn this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

but to a more pixel-perfect way, using photoshop. How can I achieve such a result? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to semi-automate this? If the subject is obvious, like in your example it can be done as shown in the steps below (this is for Photoshop CC, won't work in older versions).

Unfortunately however, if the image has a complex subject and background, it might not work as expected. A manual crop with the Crop Tool might be necessary.

Anyway . . .

1. Do *Select > Subject*
2. If you need a border around the crop, do *Select > Expand*, set the number of pixels to expand by, otherwise skip this step
3. Do *Image > Crop*

Note: You could also record these as an Action if you want to automate it further. You could set up a function key to call the Action, and  you could also run the Action using *File > Automate > Batch* on a whole folder full of images.

Comment: Yes, automate it for a folder full of images. Thanks for your reply, I will try it tomorrow at work =)